# Как убрать рамку(отступов) при нажатии на кнопки управления?

Tags: css3, html5, scss

[image: tagam]
при нажатии на кнопки управления подсвечивается рамка отступов, Как убрать???

Comment: @MAX не помогло,  класс owl-dot внутри span

Comment: если помогло - то отметьте решением, и как-то вы странно комментируете. Как минимум это нужно делать непосредственно под ответом, чтобы ответивший мог отследить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*:focus,a:focus {outline: none;}

Если не поможет - то рабочий пример в студию.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже на слайдер owl. Он для «точек» использует тэг BUTTON, что автоматом присваивает «точкам» стили кнопок. Нужно перекрыть «паразитные» стили примерно так:

```
.owl-carousel button, 
.owl-carousel button:hover {
    background: transparent;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}
```

CSS-cвойства подберите под свою задачу.

В качестве другого решения, через инспектор браузера определите какой css-класс используется для «точек» и переопределите его «паразитные» свойства с **!important**.

Comment: @Kjuri помогло спасибо большое!!